I did an "undo commit" in github desktop and now I want to undo the undo. Is this possible, or is that commit lost?
I wanted to undo the commit because it included some files that should not be in the repo, so I thought I could undo the commit and then re-save the one file that should be in the commit. Unfortunately when I did the undo, my editor got confused and loaded the (now checked out) older version of the file I was editing and so lost all of the changes.
The replaced file is not in Recycle bin like it would be if you did "discard changes" and there does not seem to be any option for undo or redo after doing an undo.

Thank god I found a way to get back the lost commit (and the newest version of the file that had been in my editor).
Open a git command window from inside the desktop client and enter the command...
git fsck --lost-found
This will list any dangling commits in the repo. This is what mine listing looked like...
D:\Github\sm-rfc-replace>git fsck --lost-found
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
dangling commit 6c12924f55c5dba93bf527be3aa810149ec5de23
dangling tree 9272dc2e7e8f0fd9b5ae0384634da436cdda874c
dangling commit a25d2eb62618a20f4d63b994d10d1c785d8cf7d7

Look for the one that you did undo on. You can check the name of a dangling commit using git status like this...
git status a25d2eb62618a20f4d63b994d10d1c785d8cf7d7
When you find the commit you lost, you can check it out like this...
git checkout a25d2eb62618a20f4d63b994d10d1c785d8cf7d7
Make sure you save any files you need before doing the checkout because once that checkout completes you will have the files that were in the commit.
From there, I made a new branch called "lost commit" and then did "carry over changes" so I could get that commit back into the tree. From there you can work with it like any other commit.
